# How to trigger a phone call through a click of a text using phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap

how can I trigger a phone call through the click of an  text using phonegap.
This is my code, please help me.

```
    <a class="my-cont" href="tel:9885599999" data-rel="external">
     9885599999
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Open Dialer using this snippet

```
    <TextView
        style="@style/small_title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Contact: 1234567890"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        />
```

> When you click on the link it will open the dialer for calling.